Finding a Rotated Center of Mass
Suppose we have a stationary cylinder of radius $R$ on top of which is balanced a rectangular slab of thickness $a$. Suppose the slab is rotated (without slipping) about an angle $\theta$, so that the point of contact of the slab with the cylinder is rotated through an angle $\theta$. I want to find out the coordinates of the centroid of the rotated slab with respect to the coordinates of the centroid of the un-rotated slab. I have drawn the following figure:

I'm having trouble getting started, and would appreciate any help. I apologize for not including any of my own work on this problem, but it consists mostly in a lot of triangles that don't seem to lead anywhere. I am happy to include my work, in keeping with the spirit of this forum, if it could be relevant.

@whatamidoing yes

Note that the problem is essentially same if, instead of rotating, the slab is just moved the slab left by an amount $(R+a/2)\tan \theta$. In order to close the gap between these two, you just need to change the coordinate system.

@MattiP. thanks for your help! I'm going to have to take a bit to figure out how to use it to answer my question. After the translation you mentioned, would the change in coordinates just amount to a rotation? And why is the translation by $(R+a/2)\tan{(\theta)}$ and not $R\tan{(\theta)}$?

We can find the displacement vector adding the following three vectors:

from the center of the cylinder to the point of contact of the slab with the cylinder

$$\vec v_1 =(R\sin \theta, R\cos \theta) $$

from the point of contact of the slab with the cylinder to the initial point of contact

$$\vec v_2 =(-R\theta\cos \theta, R\theta\sin \theta) $$

from the initial point of contact to the center of mass

$$\vec v_3 =\left(\frac a2\sin \theta, \frac a2\cos \theta\right)$$
and then subtracting the initial position vector of the center of mass with respect to the center of the cylinder
$$\vec v_4 =\left(0, R+\frac a2\right)$$
that is
$$\vec v_1+\vec v_2+\vec v_3-\vec v_4 =\left(\left(R+\frac a2\right)\sin \theta-R\theta\cos \theta, \left(R+\frac a2\right)(\cos \theta-1)+R\theta\sin \theta\right)$$


Thank you for your thorough response! I just have one question. In deriving the expression for $\mathbf{v}{2}$, you have that its length is $R\theta$. Is this exact? I thought $R\theta$ was the length of arc of the circle subtended by the angle $\theta$, but is it also the length of $\mathbf{v}{2}$?

@GeorgyZhukov Yes of course, because the slab rotates without slipping, the length is the same.

Ah, of course. Thank you very much.

HINT:
Two things to be considered here while finding locus of C:

The slab edge $P'T' $ is like a taut string and when it rolls, the initial point displaces $ P\to P', T\to T', S\to S' $ while describing an involute (red). "String" length equals arc length $ P'T'= R \theta $.

The base of the triangle $C'P'T'=P'T' $is variable, the length of "taut string".

Consider the length of the "unwound string" line segment $P'T' $ as hypotenuse to find Center of Mass by $(x,y)$ projections (green) directly.

In this rough sketch it should be noted that the coincident point $(P,T,Q,S)$ disassociated into four separate points $(P',T',Q',S')$
$$(x'',y'')=$$
$$ R(\sin \theta - \theta \cos \theta ) + a \sin \theta/2 +R (\cos \theta + \theta \sin \theta )+ a \cos \theta/2$$
We may call it as a modified circle involute.
Another very rough sketch of C locus when slab rolls on the circle $(R=1, a=0.4)$ :


